# Gridview Paging is always on

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging

I want to turn paging off on a gridview, however, I can't seem to turn it off and I don't understand hwy it is on to begin with.

This seems like such a basic issue, but I can't seem to find anyone having the same issue. I can find plenty of people having issues in turning paging on, but no one turning it off.

ASP.Net Code

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="tcQuestions" runat="server" Width="100%" ActiveTabIndex="2">
    <asp:TabPanel ID="tpAll" runat="server" HeaderText="All Questions" ScrollBars="None">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAll" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvAllQuestions" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsQuestions" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="False" Width="100%">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="QuestionRef" HeaderText="Ref" DataNavigateUrlFields="FkSection,QuestionID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="questions/{0}/{1}">
                                <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:HyperLinkField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionText" HeaderText="Question" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Period" HeaderText="Frequency">
                                <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ValidFrom" HeaderText="Start From" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yy}">
                                <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ObsoleteDate" HeaderText="Next Review" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yy}">
                                <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsQuestions" runat="server"
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationConnectionString %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT QuestionID, QuestionRef, QuestionText, FkSection, Period, ValidFrom, ObsoleteDate FROM Questions WHERE [FkSection] = @SectionID ORDER BY Obsolete, ObsoleteDate Desc">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSections" Name="SectionID" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
```

There is no code behind affecting the gridview.

Comment: try giving `AllowPaging = false` to the gridview and check

Comment: Search for `AllowPaging` project wide.

Comment: @Nadeem - Already tried that, thanks though

Comment: @TimSchmelter - With the aim of what?

Comment: @Weiz_ell: since `AllowPaging` is `off` by default and your codebehind doesn't contain code which modifies the `GridView` the only conclusion left is that some code elsewhere modifies this setting. **Edit** Now you have edited your question to include `AllowPaging="False"` which doesn't change anything since that's the default.

Comment: @Weiz_ell: Can you show us how you are binding the gridview ?

Comment: @Nadeem - I am not doing it ... its happening through the DataSourceID property, so its done in the background, not by any code I have written